# Spring corrupts Excel(xlsx, xls) file when uploading to the server (org.apache.poi)

Tags: java, excel, spring-boot, apache-poi, thymeleaf

I am uploading an Excel file using spring but apache POI cannot read the file because its either corrupt or in a different format. but this only happens when I upload the Excel file. the Excel file opens well before its uploaded. Iam using POI version 3.17

Here is my Code.

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="/uploadExcelFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="categoriesForMessages" class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <label>Upload File</label>
            <input id="form-control-9" name="file" type="file" accept=".xls,.xlsx">
            <p class="help-block">
                <small>Upload Excel types .xls .xlsx</small>
            </p>
        </div>
</form>
```

Controller

```
public class XController {

    @PostMapping("/uploadExcelFile")
    public String uploadFile(Model model, MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

        File currDir = new File(".");
        String path = currDir.getAbsolutePath();
        fileLocation = path.substring(0, path.length() - 1) + file.getOriginalFilename();
        System.out.println(fileLocation);
        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(fileLocation);

        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileLocation);
            Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
            fis.close();

            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            Row row = sheet.getRow(0);

            System.out.println(row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue());

        } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "redirect:/home";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the file outputstream and file inputstream are pointing to the new file? You are reading a file that doesn't exist. Its not the spring who currupts the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are trying to read an empty file which you have just created. But you should have read the `multipart-file` to create the workbook.

```
       FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileLocation); // fis created with new file location 
        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(fis); //creating a workbook with an empty file
```

If you are trying to read from the workbook, You can directly make use of the `MultipartFile` object and be done with it. No need to create a new `File`.

Do something like this.

```
  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file.getInputStream());
```

and then go on and work with the file. If you want to save the file somewhere, you can do it like,

```
try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("/path/to/your/file/hello.xlsx")) {
            workbook.write(outputStream);
}
```